# Javascript bind on object literal methods not working

Tags: javascript, bind

The bind method does not transfer the 't' variable as the new 'this' keyword to the "ob.bind_part()' object literal function?

```js
var ob = {

  "first": function() {
    console.log("first function");
    var t = "new bind";
    ob.bind_part.bind(t);
  },


  "bind_part": function() {
    console.log(this.toString());
  }

};


(function() {
  ob.first();

  ob.bind_part(); // returns the 'ob' object instead of the bind

})();
```

However, instead of bind if 'call' is used

```
 ob.bind_part.call(t); //THIS WORKS
```

it works?

any idea why bind does not work?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) returns a new function, you have to assign it to `obj.bind_part`

```js
var ob = {

  "first": function() {
    console.log("first function");
    var t = "new bind";
    ob.bind_part = ob.bind_part.bind(t);
  },


  "bind_part": function() {
    console.log(this.toString());
  }

};


(function() {
  ob.first();

  ob.bind_part(); // returns "new bind"

})();
```

Comment: @user3464127 No need, there's a test embedded in the answer already :) Press "Run code snippet" and check your console

Answer (score 0):

The [`.bind()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) does not mutate a function, instead it returns a new one. You're not doing anything with the return value. The following would work:

```
ob.bind_part = ob.bind_part.bind(t);
```

Answer (score 0):

`.bind()` returns a new function which you need to assign back to your calling object.

```
ob.bind_part = ob.bind_part.bind(t);
```